# Qt6: "Unable to read Memory" when pointing to a QLineEdit from a QFormLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I want to get the text from a QLineEdit, which is in a QFormLayout, to save it to a File. The saving works fine, but I am not able to get the text form the QLineEdit and when I look at it from the Debugger it says "Unable to read Memory". I can´t figure out how to correctly point to the QLineEdit, so that I can get the text.

With this code I want to get the text:

```
QJsonArray Kegelbuch::saveSettings() {
    QFormLayout* formLayout = (QFormLayout*)ui.einstellungenTab->layout();
    QJsonArray data;
    QLineEdit* settingsEdit;

    for (int i = 0; i < formLayout->rowCount(); i++) {
        settingsEdit = (QLineEdit*)formLayout->itemAt(i, QFormLayout::ItemRole::FieldRole);
    }

    return data;
}
```

How the window looks:
[image: EinstellungentTab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`settingsEdit = (QLineEdit*)formLayout->itemAt(i, QFormLayout::ItemRole::FieldRole);`

with

`settingsEdit = (QLineEdit*)(formLayout->itemAt(i, FormLayout::ItemRole::FieldRole)->widget());`

Background: `itemAt()` returns a `QLayoutItem*`, so you need to call `QWidget *QLayoutItem::widget()` to get the widget.

Comment: Now data is being read but everything inside data, like "window_state" says "Unable to read Memory" and I still cant read the text

Comment: @Bugsia What exactly does "cant read  the text" mean? What does "QLineEdit::text()" return? That something strange is displayed inside the dubugger does not necessarily mean that something is wrong. Also, you might try a ``qobject_cast`` instead of te crude C-style cast and check, that the returned pointer is not a ``nullptr``, i.e. if the cast to ``QLineEdit*`` was in fact successful.

Comment: It actually works and it just throws an error when I try to access the text from the last row with the Buttons. Thanks!